# Rails - multiple "workflows" on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workflow

I'm using the workflow gem on some of my models in order to implement a state machine.
is it possible to have multiple "workflows" on the same model?

Answer (score 0):

Using some ruby meta-programming (see [Storing workflows (state machines) in the DB. What's the best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586559/storing-workflows-state-machines-in-the-db-whats-the-best-way)) this should be easily accomplished. I'm working out a solution in this vein to use for myself, and hopefully for an eventual pull into the docs if I can get it worked out.

However, if you have a finite number of workflows with predefined steps, you could just follow the example from the readme at https://github.com/geekq/workflow/#individual-workflows-for-objects